# Number of permutations? (2 groups of n elements with a condition)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given the set of elements $\{a_1 \dots a_n\}$ and $\{b_1 \dots b_n\}$

How many permutations of all $2n$ elements are there such that $a_i$ is to the left of $b_j$ for all $i \leq j$?

$n=1$ gives $1$ permutation

$\{a_1, b_1\}$

$n=2$ gives $5$ permutations

$\{a_1,a_2,b_2,b_1\}$,

$\{a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2\}$,

$\{a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2\}$,

$\{a_2,a_1,b_1,b_2\}$,

$\{a_2,a_1,b_2,b_1\}$

$n=3$ gives $57$ permutations

$n=4$ gives $1145$ permutations

$n=5$ gives $35505$ permutations

$n=6$ gives $1566813$ permutations

$n=7$ gives $93109737$ permutations (7 hours to calculate)

$n=8$ gives $7158444465$ permutations (Jaap Scherphuis)

This sequence is not yet on OEIS, so I have been unable to look up a formula.
Does appear in A276837 in column n row 2n

Thanks in advance for any help,

Ben Crossley

Comment: I get the same numbers as you, and $7158444465$ for $n=8$.

Comment: These numbers occur in [A276837](http://oeis.org/A276837) at column $n$, row $2n$. No formula is listed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(n,k)$ be the number of such permutations on two sets of $n$ elements where the rightmost element $a_i$ from the first set is at position $k$.

Clearly, for any $n>0$, $f(n,k)>0$ only if $n\le k<2n$.

By considering the possible positions of each new pair $(a_n,b_n)$, you will find that $$f(n,k)=(2n-k)\cdot k\cdot f(n-1,k-1)+(2n-k)\sum_{i=n-1}^{k-2} f(n-1,i)$$

Let $f(n)=\sum_k f(n,k)$. Using the recurrence above, I got the following values:

$f(1)=1\\
f(2)=5\\
f(3)=57\\
f(4)=1145\\
f(5)=35505\\
f(6)=1566813\\
f(7)=93109737\\
f(8)=7158444465\\
f(9)=690665206113\\
f(10)=81648757479285\\
f(11)=11600465117974425\\
f(12)=1949518933483370409\\
f(13)=382385860587332190225\\
f(14)=86548201546165179374925\\
f(15)=22384061540470612338958665\\
f(16)=6558992881564560855032903265\\
f(17)=2161200782586444088187793593025\\
f(18)=795476007328144767489928007834085\\
f(19)=325131395894891669468123689359576825\\
f(20)=146784397748821461094492189898168139225\\$